# Need Unique clients with maixmum count first according to high priority

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a table in which clients have high to low priority. I want to see Maximum high priority unique clients first. Here is my [current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlwp3.jpg).

and I want to see output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNONJ.jpg)

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: please click on (this is my table content ) it shows the content of my db table and (this image should be output ) this what i need

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! On this site, you have to *find your problem*, and then, if you don't know how to solve it, ask. But never skip the first step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will work as you want

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS coun,`client`,priority FROM `pi` 
WHERE  priority='high' GROUP BY `client`,priority ORDER BY coun DESC
```

Response if you need same as i wrote above.

Comment: Wow, TIL that you can do this in MySQL! +1

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE Priority='high' AND client= 'a');
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;

I think this helps...

Comment: this will only show client "a" not "b". please check output

Comment: I have just placed a demo.Use OR instead of AND with client b and a

Answer (score 0):

### Interpretation

OK, I think I get what you're asking, correct me if I am wrong:

You want to get the number of high priority entries for each client in the database - i.e. for client "a" you want the number "3", because "a" has 3 high priority entries. Client "b" only has one, so you want the number "1" returned for him.

### Implementation

We're going to need to use PHP for this. Lets start by querying the database:

```
SELECT client, priority FROM pi ORDER BY client
```

The query selects the values for the `client` and `priority` columns in each table row. It is ordered by the `client` column so that all clients are grouped together - this will be important later on.

Now, what we're going to do is loop through every result from our query. As long as `client` is the same, and `priority` is high, we increment a counter. When `client` changes (i.e. we reach a different client), we echo out the value for `client` and the counter, thus creating the table that OP wants. We then reset the counter, and start doing the same thing for the new client.

### Code

Here is the final PHP code for your problem:

```
<?php
$c = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
$q = "SELECT client, priority FROM pi ORDER BY client";
$r = mysqli_query($c,$q);
$a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
$client = $a["client"];
$count = 0;
echo "<table><tr><td>Client</td><td>Priority</td></tr>";
while ($a!=null) {
    if ($a["client"]!=$client) {
        echo "<tr><td>$client</td><td>$count</td></tr>";
        $client = $a["client"];
        $count = 0;
    }
    if ($a["priority"]=="high") {
        $count++;
    }
    $a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
}
echo "<tr><td>$client</td><td>$count</td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: i tried your code but its not working. please check the out put image.

Comment: yep it worked now thank you and i also wanted to show priority in that